# How to navigate from screen flow to lwc component passing parameters

Tags: lightning-web-components, screen-flow, lightningnavigation

We have a screen flow. On click of a button/link and based on a condition, it needs to navigate to

1. an LWC component passing a parameter to the URL which can be accessed in that LWC component (if the condition matches in the flow)
2. standard files related list (if the condition doesnt match in the flow)

Any pointers on implementation of the above scenario are highly appreciated. If you have a sample code link for the same please share.

Comment: Did you take a look at this article?
https://unofficialsf.com/adding-lightning-web-components-to-flow-screens/
Not e- you wouldn't pass nay params via a URL - it would be as api variable exposed in the LWC